# Listview Right-Click Drag After Left-Click Drag Removes Item

Tags: vb.net, listview

Here's the scenario:

1. Using the left mouse button, drag an item from a Listview (Details view) onto a drop target. All is good.
2. Using the right mouse button, perform the same action. All is good, shows that behavior is the same as with the left mouse button.
3. Using the left mouse button, drag an item from the Listview onto a drop target, where the target removes the dragged item from the Listview. All is good -- the item is removed.
4. Repeat #3. All is good -- the item is removed, shows that subsequent items can be dragged successfully without any other mouse gestures.
5. Using the right mouse, repeat #3. All is NOT good -- the drag action is never started.
6. Using the left mouse button, click an item in the Listview and release it.
7. Using the right mouse button, drag the item to a a drop target. All is good!

So to summarize, items dragged from a Listview using the left or right mouse button work the same. However, once the drop target removes an item from the Listview (doesn't even matter if it is the dragged item) the right mouse drag ceases to work until a Listview item is clicked using the left mouse button.

Is this expected behavior and if so why? Is there a workaround so I can have both the left and right mouse buttons work the same?

Here's the relevant code:

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemDrag(sender As Object, e As ItemDragEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemDrag
    ListView1.DoDragDrop(ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0), DragDropEffects.Link)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.DragDrop
    Dim item As ListViewItem = e.Data.GetData(GetType(ListViewItem))
    If rbRemove.Checked Then
        Dim index As Int32 = ListView1.SelectedIndices.Item(0)
        For i As Int32 = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
            Dim item1 As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items(i)
            If item1 Is item Then
                ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
                Exit For
            End If
            If index >= ListView1.Items.Count Then
                index -= 1
            End If
            ListView1.Items(index).Selected = True
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_DragOver(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.DragOver
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not an expected behaviour AFAIK. Sounds like a bug... Could you perhaps show us some sample code?

Comment: Sure, just added it to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer not to be doing this, but this seems to be a workaround:

```
Private activeDrag As Boolean
Private Sub ListView1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseMove
    If (Not activeDrag) AndAlso (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right) AndAlso (Me.ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) Then
        Dim x As ItemDragEventArgs = New ItemDragEventArgs(e.Button, Me.ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0))
        Me.ListView1_ItemDrag(Me, x)
    End If

End Sub
```

The activeDrag variable is set to true before DoDragDrop is called, then set to false when it returns.